# Where has cartogram plugin for QGIS gone?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, cartogram

This plugin used to be downloadable from Carson Farmer's plugin repository page. However, the repository is broken.

An old version of the plugin source code is still available at https://code.google.com/p/ftools-qgis/ but using QGIS 1.8 the plugin cannot be loaded ("corrupted").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.12 it (Cartogram plugin version: 1.0.0, on windows 10) works fine, just did a check.You have to wait a few seconds...

Answer (score 10):

The latest version of the Cartogram plugin, which works in QGIS 2.2, is here: https://github.com/CristianCantoro/cartogram-plugin , pending a [pull request](https://github.com/cfarmer/cartogram-plugin/pull/2).

To prove it works in 2.2 I created a bendy map of London with it:

[carto http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15008199/Images-2-share/carto-2.2.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15008199/Images-2-share/carto-2.2.png)

To install, unzip/clone the repository into the qgis2/python/plugins folder. E.g., this is how I did it on my Linux system:

`mv repos/cartogram-plugin-master ~/.qgis2/python/plugins/`

You should then find the icon in QGIS's top bar next time you load it.

[image: cartogram]

Answer (score 6):

Carson Farmer's repository may be out of commission for the time being, however there are a number of other options for creating cartograms like the one you described.

Cart, by Gastner and Newman using their diffusion-based method 
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/cart/

Cartograms, by Widdle (for Windows)
http://www.griddle-gidata-analysis.com/page2.htm

ScapeToad, by Choros Laboratory using the diffusion-based method: 
http://scapetoad.choros.ch/index.php

Provotis, by Stanford Visualization Group includes tool for Dorling Cartograms 
http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/

IndieMapper, by Axis Maps produces noncontiguous cartograms 
http://indiemapper.com/app/