# How to update a QGIS plugin for new version (2.2)?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2, cartogram

The updates to QGIS 2.2 have been fantastic and I'm really liking the improvements to the interface, features and performance. However, it seems that some plugins have not survived the upgrade.

cartogram-plugin is one such example, about which there is already [a question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72328/where-has-the-cartogram-plugin-for-qgis-gone) on this site. My question is not where it has gone, but how I can help get it working again. The latest version of it is, I believe, on [GitHub](https://github.com/cfarmer/cartogram-plugin), meaning that a collaborative effort should be able to get it running on QGIS 2.2 is possible.

I am up for giving this a try but would like some advice from the community before I start. Where's the best place to start? There seems to be plenty of advice for people wanting to create *new* plugins - like the [PyPGIS Developer Cookbook](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html#pyqgis-developer-cookbook) and the [Plugin Builder plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pluginbuilder/). But what about info for people like me who want to upgrade an existing plugin? Sure there is much work to be done in this area, so the answer may be of use beyond cartogram-plugin.

To some extent the question depends on the differences between QGIS 1.x and 2.x. Does that mean this is a good place to start? http://qgis.org/api/2.0/classQgisInterface.html

Many thanks,

Robin

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to answer my own question but the Cartogram Plugin has now been fixed, providing an immediate answer to the question. Based on the successful [upgrade](https://github.com/cfarmer/cartogram-plugin/pull/2) of Cartogram Plugin by Christian Cantoro, this is where to start http://documentation.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html

The specific changes needed in this instance can be seen in the [diff](https://github.com/CristianCantoro/cartogram-plugin/compare/cfarmer:master...master) between the old and new versions.