# Python Error while installing Cartogram

Tags: qgis, installation, cartogram

I am quite new to GIS and qGIS especially.

I would like to install cfarmers cartogram plugin. From what I understand, this has to be done manually - so I 've followed the instructions from RobinLoveLace (see link below).

[Where has the cartogram plugin for QGIS gone?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72328/where-has-the-cartogram-plugin-for-qgis-gone)

When I try to click the icon for the Cartogram Creator, I get an error message (see below).

Any tips on how to get it to work?

> An error has occured while executing Python code:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\cartogram\plugin.py", line 136, in run
>       d = doCartogram.Dialog(self.iface)
>     File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\cartogram\doCartogram.py", line 61, in **init**
>       for name, layer in layermap.iteritems():
>     File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\cartogram\doCartogram.py", line 61, in **init**
>       for name, layer in layermap.iteritems():
>     File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\bdb.py", line 49, in trace_dispatch
>       return self.dispatch_line(frame)
>     File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\bdb.py", line 68, in dispatch_line
>       if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
>   BdbQuit
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>
> QGIS version:
>   2.4.0-Chugiak Chugiak, 8fdd08a
>
> Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~2/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/HEC/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/HEC/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\GDAL-1.11.0-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.6.1-> py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\Users\HEC\.qgis2\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms',     'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

>

The plugin for Cartogram Creator for qGIS is downloaded from here: https://github.com/cfarmer/cartogram-plugin/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

The Cartogram plugin is not compatible with QGIS 2.x since it is not being maintained anymore. The only way to get it work is to get a developer to update it.