# Is it possible to animate a cartogram with FOSS GIS?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, animation, cartogram

I was wondering if anyone knows of any FOSS tools to animate cartograms?

By this, I mean '[tweening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbetweening)' between the geographic shapefile and the cartogram version of a shapefile.

This means gradually changing / morphing / interpolating one polygon into another. The "before" and "after" polygons have identical numbers of nodes, but each of these nodes will have different positions.

There's an [example here on the ESRI blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/apl/2012/03/07/animated-cartograms/).

They don't do the animation uniformly, they pass across the polygons in increasing longitude order, but it gives an idea of the effect I'm after.

I've been using [ScapeToad](http://scapetoad.choros.ch/) to do cartograms, and it looks as if it generates a cartogram shapefile with the same number and order of vertices as the original shapefile.

This means I should be able to write code that interpolates each node along a line from its geographic position to its distorted position - perhaps with 'easing' (so the position on the line isn't linear interpolation, more like points on a sine-wave)

**Is there already a library or plugin which can interpolate polygons in this way?**

Comment: have you seen this QGIS plugin, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72328/where-has-the-cartogram-plugin-for-qgis-gone.  You could take a look at the python source code.

Comment: thanks for that, I hadn't seen that plugin. It looks as if it needs a bit of work on it to get it working on the newer versions of QGIS, though.

Comment: There are cartograms made with d3 and TopoJSON that achieve a similar effect to what you want, check e.g. [http://prag.ma/code/d3-cartogram](http://prag.ma/code/d3-cartogram)

Answer (score 2):

yes! I worked it out.

ScapeToad outputs mixed geometries - MULTIPOLYGON and POLYGON. I fixed this using "Multiparts to Single Parts". It also interpolates, so that there are more points in the output polygons (this depends on the quality setting).

To get around this, I used the [QChainage plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qchainage/) to create 200 equally spaced points on both the original and cartogram polygons (I had to convert these layers to lines first). This doesn't guarantee 200 points per polygon - either 200 or 201.

Next, export the two chainage POINT layers as CSV, with XY geometry.

Finally, a quick Python script to interpolate each point so that it's 50% of the way to the same point in the cartogram!

White is the original shapefile, red is the cartogram shapefile, and yellow is the 50% interpolation between the two.

[image]

With a bit of work, I should be able to use the Time Manager plugin by @underdark to do an animation...

Comment: how about the "quick" Python script, so ppl could really benefit from your findings? ;

Comment: @Bernd V. I'll put it on Github once I've got it to work with Time Manager ;)